# Drupal commerce. How to show only products suitable for selected vehicle?

Tags: 7, commerce

Any ideas how to tackle following scenario with Drupal Commerce?

User selects his own vehicle from select drop-downs. Vehicle consists of following attributes: vehicle type, manufacturer, year, model. Then, by clicking any product category, user gets a view of products in that category that are suitable for the currently selected vehicle.

There are 50000 products in Excel file (with unique SKU), 8500 different vehicles as csv (with unique vehicle id and each vehicle attribute in their own columns), there are going to be 800+ product categories with many subcategories (snow mobiles, scooters, engine parts, exhaust pipe systems…) Many products may fit in many vehicles.

So where to start? How to match products with vehicles? How to match products with categories? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

General solution is to use [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/Entityreference).

You need two entity types:

1. Cars
2. Products

Products you have already, thanks to commerce. Cars can well be nodes so you can create content type for them using GUI. To products add entity reference pointing to cars. Then create a [view](https://drupal.org/project/Views) with product to car relationship, filtered by car.

For categories, use regular taxonomy.